# Devices with different resolutions accessing same drawable-xxxx folder

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-resources, android-drawable

I am developing an app for all the available screen resolutions. My approach is to create different `drawable` folders and to keep respective images in them. Everything was going fine before I found a clash between two devices of different resolutions. Devices are of `480*800` and `600*1024` resolution. But according to their pixel density they are accessing same `drawable` folder `drawable-hdpi`(which is also according to given specification in this image below).

[image]

My problem is that images in this folder are perfect for one device and not for other. It means if I keep images for `600*1024`, they are overlapping in other device `480*800` and all that. I have tried renaming the folder to other possible names but couldn't succeed. Please help me on how can I handle this situation. Hope I have described my situation clearly...

Comment: be a little more creative use relative layout and use appropriate scaling in image view so it will adjust -- you can also use weights in liniar layout

Comment: I m using relative layout, but I will try weight approach in linear layout, I think it can help...Thanks...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can put your all Images in drawable folder and then you create a layout folders like this

**Layout-small**

**Layout-large**

**Layout-xlarge**

So that you can access all the images from same drawable folder and while you run your app it automatically creates drawable folders in bin according to their sizes so that no conflicts & overlaps occurs . So check this way .............

Comment: See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) on configuration qualifiers. I think that will help.

Comment: @androidgeek: what size images should i keep in drawable folder..??

Comment: you can keep all sizes of images in drawable folder , but make a difference for example logo.png image for small screen you can also keep logo_large.png in same folder no problem and also don't want to create drawable-hdpi etc...........

Comment: ohhk..I was unaware of this approach...can you please give few more examples for naming images for different resolutions...because i think problem will persist as both devices will again access same image say logo_large_hdpi.png....please help...

Comment: This is a terrible approach, please don't do this. Putting all of your images in the root drawable folder will cause them to be scaled at runtime, lowering the image quality and performance.

Comment: For example i have an image size of 45*45 for 240*320 screen size i name as logo_small.png, and image size of 120*120 for large screen i name it as logo_large.png and 256*256 for Xlarge i name it as logo_xlarge.png and i put all these images in drawable and i access from different screen size layout folders........

Comment: Why on earth would you do that when you could just put them in `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, and let Android handle it the way that it's supposed to. Hell, if you need to select images based on screen size (e.g. large, xlarge) which is unusual but whatever, you can put them in `drawable-large`, `drawable-xlarge`. Your images are STILL GOING to be scaled if you put them in the root drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `drawable` folder and keep the images with what size you want (let it be 30px*20px) add that in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @androidgeek's answer to cater your specific need what you can do is that you can create this layout folder

res/layout-sw600dp

in this layout you can create the layout for 600*1024 device resolution and you can use seperate drawables for this layout.

Also you can try taking a xhdpi images only and resizing it at runtime from your code which ofcourse isn't suggested approach but is effective most of the times

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of misinformation in here. The resolution alone does *not* determine the pixel density. A 480 x 800 px screen could be `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, or `xxhdpi`. You can't determine what density bucket a screen falls in by its resolution alone. The `ldpi`, `mdpi`, etc. qualifiers tell you the DENSITY of pixels per inch (roughly -- they're not exact, but close). An `hdpi` screen will have around 240 pixels across in 1 inch of the screen, an `mdpi` screen will have around 160, etc.

You *cannot* use density to target a resolution. Period.

If you're trying to make an application that works on very specific resolutions, I'd suggest developing for iOS instead.

Answer (score -1):

Different devices get there images from different folders, its a flaw in android devices even if its a tab its not necessary that it will get its images from drawable-xlarge.
For this i would suggest you to make different folders for different devices. if you are making application which will run perfectly on all devices.
try

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-hdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-sw600

drawable-large-hdpi

above all folders covers almost all devices.
You dont need to insert different images in every folder for different devices, Because if you have images in hdpi folder then mdpi and ldpi automatically scale those images,
in some case it may be possible that images didnt fit properly for those case you have to insert images according to its size.